# QGIS rule-based labelling base on active map layers

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers, rule-based

I'm new to QGIS.

I'm currently using the new version 3.20.0 Odense and I have some troubles setting up the rule-based labelling for a layer.

Essentially, what I need is to automatically swap labels base on active layers; I don't even know if it's possible but I have tried several conditional statements in conjunction with `is_layer_visible` and everything seems to be pointless...

I have my map set (Positron - retina) and three other layers, two of them plotting different entities and the third one is a summary SVG icon displayed on each of the five continents.

This last layer is the one for which I would like labels to become visible based on which of the other two layers I selected from the **Layers Panel** on the right.

Comment: You want to label layer C based on whether layer A or layer B is activated, is this correct? What should happen when both layer A and B are visible? Have you considered duplicating layer C, setting the correct labels and turning it on/off along with the corresponding layer A/B?

Comment: Yes, I have considered that option (it's actually what I'm doing right now); however, I just wanted to have some more "interactive" features on my map... with that said to answer your first question when both layers are not visible labels should disappear too.

Answer (score 3):

Set a rule based label with Filter `is_layer_visible ('layer1')` an the label settings for layer 1 (see screenshot 1). Copy and paste this rule and adapt is (see screenshot 2). When you now toggle visibility of layer1 and layer2, the label on layer3 will adapt and show the layer for the layer(s) that is (are) visible.

*Screenshot 1:*
[image]

*Screenshot 2:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately, for some reasons both labels are printed on map... even when I deselect both layers. I honestly don't know why, it could be because I'm importing the labels form a .csv?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you meant with "iport labels form a csv". Easiest to understand your very problem would be sharing your project+data (at least a sample or dummy data). Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

I had to submit my project so, I opted for the easiest solution: two label layers... however, now that it's all done I'm more than happy to learn how to do a proper conditional labelling.

I followed the steps @Babel indicated in his answer and what I need is basically for the layer called *conditional labelling* (when is selected) to show different labels based on the active layers, namely **integrated_data-GA100Kexcluded** and **integrated_data-GA100Kincluded**.

Below some screenshots, I hope they can help. Let me know.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).